# How to set the width of Datagridcolumn based on the the width of the content placed in Datagrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, datagridviewcolumn

I want to set the width of Datagridcolumn such that the columns width should size based on the content placed in Datagrid cell such that there should be 
equal space between columns.

This is what i tried so far:

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="MyGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderBrush="Transparent"  
        GridLinesVisibility="None" Background="Transparent" RowHeaderWidth="0" > 
 <DataGrid.Resources>
 <Style  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
     <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
     <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,5"/>
 </Style>
 </DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header = "Column 1">
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}" Width=120 TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
                   </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>  

        <DataGridTemplateColumn ..../>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn ..../>             
</DataGrid.Columns>
</Datagrid>
```

Some thing like this (as shown below) where there is equal space between columns and the columns are adjusted based on the width of content defined in data-grid cell.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try, string width can be calculated using the [TextFomratter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.textformatting.textformatter?view=netframework-4.7.2) class(**assuming your grid contains only text**), 
So you would need to pass have a way to calculate the width of the biggest column, which can be calculated by using a binding - RelativePath,etc

```
private Size MeasureString(string candidate)
{
    var formattedText = new FormattedText(
        candidate,
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface(this.textBlock.FontFamily, this.textBlock.FontStyle, this.textBlock.FontWeight, this.textBlock.FontStretch),
        this.textBlock.FontSize,
        Brushes.Black,
        new NumberSubstitution(),
        1);

    return new Size(formattedText.Width, formattedText.Height);
}
```

You can use the above code with a [MultiConverter](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/wpf-multivalue-converters/) to get the a reference to the parent Grid object that you can use with a forloop to calculate the highest width at the current time, from there you might need to update all columns with the new column width.

You would need to have text + Grid parent object as the parameters for the multiconverter.